# Remove an element from vector and change the size

Tags: c++, vector

I try to remove elements from a vector and it works fine with the erase() methode, but after removing the element the size of the vector still the same.

```
std::vector<int> myvector;
myvector.push_back (1);
myvector.push_back (2);
myvector.push_back (3);//here the size is 3
myvector.erase(myvector.begin()+1);//I think normally the size should be 2 after removing the element
```

is there a function that can do that or should I do it manually, I'm new to c++ I checked the documentation and I didn't found a solution for this.

Comment: Did you actually check what `size()` returns after your erase call?

Comment: I checked the size after I called erase() and it is still the same

Comment: Then your standard library it broken.

Comment: @MohamedBouallegue: That can't be.  It works for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/362855c5978fa308.  Can you show more of your code? Perhaps you made an accidental copy?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thank you guys, I expected the erase function to change the size after removing the element(which is meaningful), but it was not working like that in my code and I didn't found in the documentation anything about changing the size, that's why I posted this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size is changed then an element of a vector is removed with using member function erase. If you mean capacity then it will not be changed.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << "v.size() = " << v.size() << std::endl;
    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    v.erase( v.begin() + 1 );

    std::cout << "v.size() = " << v.size() << std::endl;
    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
v.size() = 3
1 2 3 
v.size() = 2
1 3
```